# Trying to call unknow function

Tags: php

I have to dynamically try, if function is **callable** (not only if exists, but if is **callable**). This is my code:

```
try {
  call_user_func($function, $arguments->arg);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $condition = $this->_object->getContent("phpCall", "return");
}
```

`$function` and `$arguments->arg` are dynamic variables, for example `$function` contains `md5` and `$arguments->arg` contains `123`.

I know that function `md5` exists in PHP, but I get this error:
`Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in...`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [is_callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

```
if (is_callable($function)){
    //do stuff here
}
```

If you're going to pass it to call_user_func, make sure $function is a string.
Alternatively, you could just do:

```
    $function($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like call_user_func expects a string with the name of the function to be called.  Are you instead sending a function pointer?